# $N_1$ and $N_2$ are cyclic submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please help me to prove the following result:

Let $R$ be a ring with $1$ and $M$ a noetherian  left $R$-module. Suppose that if $N_1$ and $N_2$ are cyclic submodules of $M$ than $N_1+N_2$ is also cyclic.

> Show that $M$ is cyclic

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Let $m_0\in M$ and assume that $m_0$ does not generate $M$. Pick an  $x_1$ not in the submodule generated by $m_0$ and let $m_1$ be a generator for the submodule generated by $m_0$ and $x_1$. Use that $M$ is Noetherian.

Comment: @ Tobias Kildetoft, i don't see how to use the fact that $M$ is  noetherian  to get a contradiction, can you please help me more? thanks in advance

Comment: Repeat the argument to get larger and larger submodules, then use that it is Noetherian.

Comment: we repeat the argument to get larger and larger submodules, we obtain $$(m_0)\subset (m_1)\subset (m_2)\subset....$$ why obtain an increasing sequence of submodules of $M$ and the process does not stop?

Comment: The process does stop. That is precisely what it means to be Noetherian.

Comment: yes but how to prove that is doesn't stop?

Comment: I never said to use contradiction, though if you must: If it stopped, then the module would be cyclic.

Comment: @ Tobias Kildetoft, this is what we have: Let $m_0\in M$ and assume that $m_0$ does not generate $M$. Pick an $x_1$ not in the submodule generated by $m_0$ and let $m_1$ be a generator for the submodule generated by $m_0$ and $x_1$. We repeat the argument to get larger and larger submodules, we obtain an ascending chain$$(m_0)\subset (m_1)\subset (m_2)\subset....$$ of submodules of $M$. Since $M$ is noetherian  there exists some integer $n_0$ such that $(m_n)=(m_{n+1})$ for all $n\ge n_0$  why does that imply that $M$ is cyclic?  and where we use the fact that $N_1+N_2$ is cyclic?

Comment: We are picking elements not in the submodule generated by various elements in order to get the next one. Since it stabilizes, this means we have reached the module itself. We are using the fact the the sum is cyclic to pick a generator at each step.

Comment: does this give $M=(m_{n_0})$?

Comment: i made a mistacke sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An often useful equivalent property to the ascending chain condition is the *maximal condition*:

> *the module $M$ is noetherian if and only if every nonempty set of submodules of $M$ has a maximal element*

(maximality is with respect to set inclusion.

Since $M$ is noetherian, the set of its cyclic submodules has a maximal element $N$; since $\{0\}$ is cyclic, this set is not empty. If $N\ne M$, then take $x\in M$, $x\notin N$. By assumption, $N+xR$ is a cyclic submodule, where $xR$ denotes the cyclic submodule generated by $x$: a contradiction to maximality, because $N+xR\supsetneq N$ as $x\in N+xR$. Hence $N=M$.

Comment: how to prove that the set of its cyclic submodules has a maximal element? and wath is $R$?

Comment: @siwar A module is noetherian if and only if every nonempty set of submodules has a maximal element (a well-known theorem). $Rx$ is the cyclic module generated by $x$.

Comment: can you please add this detail to your answer before i cleack to accept your answer? you can also precise the  fact that  the set of its cyclic submodules is not empty, and ''contradiction with the fact that $N$ is maximal". Thanks

Comment: @siwar I added the details, but it would be much better if you train to work out them by yourself. You'll learn faster.

Comment: i think you should write $\left\{1\right\}$ is cyclic

Comment: @siwar What's $1$ in a module?

Comment: so where we use that the ring is with 1?

Comment: @siwar Since $R$ has $1$, the notion of cyclic module is well-defined to begin with: $x=x1\in xR$.

Comment: Thanks a lot egreg for your explanation!

Answer (score -1):

@ Tobias Kildetoft , Is it right if i answer like the following:

Let $m_0\in M$ and assume that $m_0$ does not generate $M$. We pick an $x_1$ not in the submodule generated by $m_0$ and let $m_1$ be a generator for the submodule generated by $m_0$ and $x_1$. We repeat the argument to get larger and larger submodules. We are picking elements not in the submodule generated by various elements in order to get the next one and  we are using the fact the the sum is cyclic to pick a generator at each step. Thus we obtain an ascending chain
$$(m_0)⊂(m_1)⊂(m_2)⊂....$$
of submodules of $M$. Since $M$ is noetherian there exists some integer $n_0$ such that $(m_n)=(m_{n+1})$ for all $n\ge n_0$.  This means we have $M=(m_{n_0})$ and thus $M$ is cyclic.